# Touch handler not called with React Native

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-native

I just started learning React Native and ran into this: I've created a component which has a `TouchableHighlight` within it, and I assigned a handler function to it, but it doesn't seem like it is getting called. Here is my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

export default class Component1 extends Component<{}> {
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log("hi there");
        this.setState({age: 22});
    }

    handlePress() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ age: prevState.age + 1 }));
        console.log("updated age");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View>
                    <Text>
                        {this.props.name}
                        {"\n"}
                        {this.state.age}
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handlePress}>
                        <View>
                            <Text>Become older</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

When I tap the "become older" view nothing is logged to the terminal (I'm using `react-native log-android`.

Thank you for helping out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `onPress`, it should be a function. You are using arrow function so, you should call the function `handlePress`:

This part:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handlePress}>
```

Should be:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handlePress()}>
```

But if you are just calling the function, so you just need to pass it in like:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handlePress}>
```

Comment: Thank you :)! I tried both options and only the first one worked (<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handlePress()}>), any idea why that could be? I'm pretty sure I've seen the other syntax used too

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the 2nd syntax, you can check the docs, it has an example that is the same as the one mentioned: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handlePress}>
```

should be

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.handlePress()}>
```

or

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handlePress}>
```